# Cutting corners with float-to-string representation?

Tags: c#, floating-point

I have a float I need to turn into a string with 5 decimals precision (X.XXXXX), which means I need to have at least 6 decimals for round up/down. The issue is that the operation to get integer representation results in a very big number which I cant store (I'd need something like Big Integer but I cant rely on any built-in stuff for compatibility reasons and I wont pretend I understand how to re-invent one, in a fairly simple manner as well). I can pre-emptively limit it:

`result = (m * Pow(5, +exp) / Pow(10,8));`

but this will only give correct results for a handful of normalized floats like `0.3f`, something like `1-E5` or `113.754f` (this now has 3 more "leading" digits for the "ceil" part) will be wrong.

Taking into account I need 5 (6) decimals precision max - is there a shortcut I can take?

Comment: What language?  Why does a printf format string with the desired width and precision not suffice?

Comment: `I cant relay on any built-in stuff`, as I said (besides basic math operations and bitshift/binary logic operations). Language is irrelevant but in this particular case is C#.

Comment: 'pow' is built in.  Why can you use that?

Comment: Because its math implementation wont change. Just like the implementation of plus, minus and divide. What it has to do with my question?

Comment: Re “I need to have at least 6 decimals for round up/down”: There is a Table Maker who would like to have a word with you.

Comment: (a) Should the result always be formatted with five digits after the decimal point (“0.12345”, ”0.00045”, “987.12345”) or with six significant digits (“8.12345”, “1234.56”, “.000123456”)? Specifically precisely how many significant digits should be produced in each possible situation. (b) Is it tolerable if there are tiny errors in rounding, such as 8.123454999 is rounded to “8.12346” instead of “8.12345” or 8.123455001 is rounded to “8.12345” instead of “8.12346”? (c) Do you have a `float` or ` double`? (d) Is there a limit on the range of the numbers?

Comment: @lzukai It is related to your question because I'm trying to understand what your question is.  It sounds like your question is "How do I implement sprintf for `f` conversion specifier?" i

Comment: @EricPostpischil Formatting is akin to `G - general` (or `Fx`) with specified decimal digits i.e `0.12345` (for 0.1f) or `123.12345` (for 123f), max precision is 5 digits after separator, padding handled separately. It CAN be less than 5 (if specified, up to 0) but no bigger. Rounding - yes, 5 and above rounds up, below 5 - rounds down. As of now super-precise rounding isnt critical. I have all basic types, I just cant rely on some framework stuff like BigInteger (since its implementation and inner structure changed between frameworks) to store big values as a result of power op.

Comment: To add: although I'm ready to sacrifice rounding quality at higher decimal count like 5, I still need stuff like `1-e5` to display correctly like `0.00001`

Comment: Since some rounding error is tolerable, why not just multiply by 100,000, round to the nearest integer, convert the integer to a string with leading zeros to at least five digits, and insert  a decimal point at the desired location?

Comment: IIRC I tried that as one of the first attempts and there were some way too severe rounding issues with stuff like aforementioned 1-e5. I will double check again, though.

Answer (score 0):

> is there a shortcut I can take?

No and yes.

No in getting the best conversion result.  Shortcuts run into the [table-maker's dilemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Table-maker%27s_dilemma).  In short, there will be corner cases that oblige a fair amount of code for float to string conversion.  Typically this means doing most of the conversion using integer math. [Example](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/212490/29485).

Yes if code is willing to tolerate some error.  This error results from the accumulated rounding of floating point operations.  As typical float has 24 bits of binary precision (akin to at least 6 significant decimal digits) the "5 decimals precision (X.XXXXX)," (which is really 6 significant decimal digits) will be hard to obtain without error.

Using wider math can greatly reduces errors (perhaps by a factor of 100s millions), yet not eliminate them.